# Optional objects in function's argument list

Tags: vba

Calling `Test1` in Excel gives 0 for any real `A` and `B`. Why does this occur?

```
Public Function Min(X As Double, y As Double, Optional y2 As Double, Optional y3 As Double) As Double
    Min = Application.WorksheetFunction.Min(X, y, y2, y3)
End Function


Function Test1(A As Double, B As Double)
    Test1 = Min(A, B)
End Function
```

In Excel: `=Test1(5,2)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Optional parameters use their default value if not passed into the function.
For doubles the default value is 0. if you do not provide `y2` or `y3` essentially, you are testing `Application.WorksheetFunction.Min(A,B,0,0)`.

If you want to change the default value, you can do something like this:

```
Public Function Min(X As Double, y As Double, Optional y2 As Double = 10000000, Optional y3 As Double = 10000000) As Double
    Min = Application.WorksheetFunction.Min(X, y, y2, y3)
End Function
```

which makes `y2` and `y3` default to `10000000` which would be your new built in artificial min.